# print out the highlighted text which follows, a single character at a time with a 10-millisecond delay between each character being displayed

Tags: javascript, html

when I click the button it will not run

Add a button with id btnPrint and value “Print” and an event handler called printString()

add a  which will be used to receive (and display) the characters in the string incrementally. This would look something like:

```
document.getElementById("outDiv").innerHTML += myNextChar;
```

Display 100 characters on a line and then start a new line, continuing until all the characters have been displayed.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercise</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function printString(){
        str="The nefarious thing about performance bugs is that the user may never know they are there - the program appears to work correctly, carrying out the correct operations, showing the right thing on the screen or printing the right text. It just does it a bit more slowly than it should have. It takes an experienced programmer, with a reasonably accurate mental model of the problem and the correct solution, to know how fast the operation should have been performed, and hence if the program is running slower than it should be";
        var myNextChar="";
        var char=0;
        function innerLoop(){
            myNextChar=str.slice(char,char+1);
            if((char+1)%100===0){
                myNextChar+="<br />"
            }
            char++;

            document.getElementById("str").innerHTML += myNextChar;

            setTimeout(innerLoop,10);
            }
        innerLoop();

        }
        //window.onload  = printString;
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="printString()">Print</button>
</body>
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at innerLoop (Exercise4.html:16)
    at printString (Exercise4.html:20)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Exercise4.html:28)
```

Comment: Your HTML contains no element with ID "str".

Comment: str="The nefarious thing about performance bu

Comment: That's a variable in your JavaScript called "str", not an Element in the HTML with id "str".  Completely different things.

Comment: sorry, I am just starting to learn this language, what should I add to solve this no element problem?

Comment: Just adding `<div id='str'></div>` to your HTML would fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need move your script to before close `</body>` tag and add a div with id str

```
<div id='str'></div>
```

```js
function printString(){
        str="The nefarious thing about performance bugs is that the user may never know they are there - the program appears to work correctly, carrying out the correct operations, showing the right thing on the screen or printing the right text. It just does it a bit more slowly than it should have. It takes an experienced programmer, with a reasonably accurate mental model of the problem and the correct solution, to know how fast the operation should have been performed, and hence if the program is running slower than it should be";
        var myNextChar="";
        var char=0;
        function innerLoop(){
            myNextChar=str.slice(char,char+1);
            if((char+1)%100===0){
                myNextChar+="<br />"
            }
            char++;

            document.getElementById("str").innerHTML += myNextChar;

            var id = setTimeout(innerLoop,10);
            if(char > str.length) clearTimeout(id);
            }
        innerLoop();

        }
        //window.onload  = printString;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercise</title>
   
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="printString()">Print</button>
 <div id='str'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not only will moving the script tag before the close of the body tag have no effect, it runs counter to the current best practices for placement of script tags.  The primary issue with the OPs code is the missing element.

Comment: I want to vote up, this solved my problem, thanks, and how do i put the print button on top of the print

Comment: I updated answer for display print button on top of the print

Comment: new question, when I click the print, it works fine but if you wait it finish you can see it is still print like space and the button keeps going down

Comment: thanks, but when the button move to the top, the "moving down" will not show